# Python code running too slow (SQLITE)

Tags: python, sqlite, optimization

I have located a piece of code that runs quite slow (in my opinion) and would liek to know what you guys think. The code in question is as follows and is supposed to:

- Query a database and get 2 fields, a field and its value
- Populate the object dictionary with their values

The code is:

```
query = "SELECT Field, Value FROM metrics " \
        "WHERE Status NOT LIKE '%ERROR%' AND Symbol LIKE '{0}'".format(self.symbol)
query = self.db.run(query, True)
if query is not None:
    for each in query:
        self.metrics[each[0].lower()] = each[1]
```

The query is run using a db class I created that is very simple:

```
def run(self, query, onerrorkeeprunning=False):
    # Run query provided and return result
    try:
        con = lite.connect(self.db)

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    con.commit()

    runsql = cur.fetchall()
    data = []
    for rows in runsql:
        line = []
        for element in rows:
            line.append(element)
        data.append(line)
    return data

except lite.Error, e:
    if onerrorkeeprunning is True:
            if con:
                con.close()
            return
    else:
        print 'Error %s:' % e.args[0]
        sys.exit(1)

finally:

    if con:
        con.close()
```

I know there are tons of ways of writting this code and I was trying to keep things simple but for 24 fields this takes 0.03s so if I have 1,000 elements that is 30s and I find it a little too long!

EDIT: on further review, `runsql = cur.fetchall()` is the line that takes the most to run.

Any help will be much appreciated.

2nd EDIT: Looking online further, I have found the issue lies with the fetchall() commant and not with my query or the initialization of the DB. Has anybody been able to imporve the performance of the result fetching? (Some people mentioned changing the SQL code but this is not to blame, it runs pretty fast but then the slowness comes when you try to grab those results)

Comment: Have you profiled the code to find out which statement is the slow one? The insertion or the fetchall; or somewhere else entirely?

Comment: Also, try it out with the command line sqlite3 command for 100 elements, and see if that takes 3 seconds; and try it with an in-memory database (in which case you can probably blame the file access to be slow).

Comment: Btw, don't you want to use the DB API parameter substitution, with '?', instead of using `.format()` directly on your query string?

Comment: Hi Evert, it is the DB initialisation and query that takes the most: the first 5 lines after `try:`. So that's SQLite and there isn't much I can do there...

Comment: Yes, but the connection part, or the execute/commit part? Also, did you try out those other suggestions?

Comment: It seems the `runsql = cur.fetchall()` line takes the most time. I have edited my original post

Comment: But have you tried an in-memory database; and tried the query on the sqlite3 command line?

Comment: You don't need `con.commit()` after a `SELECT` query; only when you're altering the database, not when querying. You can remove that statement.

Comment: You can also iterate directly over the `cur.fetchall()`, like: `for rows in cur.fetchall()`.

Comment: Thanks again Evert, a few things: I need commit because the function is general so sometimes the user may use SELECT statments and other UPDATE ones. Most of the slowness comes from `cur.fetchall()` not the initialisation or the `for...` statment. Therefore it is not a slowness on the iteration or the database initialisation (that I suppose will mean a slow file system). I will try the other tips and revert

Comment: What indices do you have on the table? Also, searching for `%ERROR%` is computationally expensive, is there an alternative that could work? I would also change `Symbol LIKE`, to `Symbol =` if you can.

Comment: Alex/Evert, added some commenta above. The slowness is comming from the fetchall() function and has nothing to do with the rest of my code (obviously everything I wrote can be improved but it is not the main cause here)

Answer (score 0):

`fetchall()` reads all results, and returns them in a temporary list.
Your `run()` function then just puts all the results into another list.
Your top-level code then copies these values into yet another dictionary.

You should fetch only the row you need (which can be done directly on the cursor), and handle it directly:

```
cur.execute("SELECT Field, Value ...")
for row in cur:
    self.metrics[row[0].lower()] = row[1]
```

Note: this distributes the cost of the SQL query over all `for` iteration; the overall time spent in the database does not change.
This code improves only on the time that would have been spent handling all the temporary variables.